# Why is tempered mcmc fit not convering well?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, mcmc, emcee

I am trying to fit a simple straight line `y=mx+c` type to some synthetic data using `parallel-tempered mcmc`. My goal is to just be able to understand how to use it, so that I can apply to some more complex models later. The example I am trying is the replica of what has already been done in a simple emcee code : 
http://dfm.io/emcee/current/user/line/
but instead of using mcmc, I want to use parallel-tempered mcmc:
http://dfm.io/emcee/current/user/pt/

Here is a working code:

```
import numpy as np
from emcee import PTSampler
import emcee

# Choose the "true" parameters.
m_true = -0.9594
b_true = 4.294
f_true = 0.534

# Generate some synthetic data from the model.
N = 50
x = np.sort(10*np.random.rand(N))
yerr = 0.1+0.5*np.random.rand(N)
y = m_true*x+b_true
y += np.abs(f_true*y) * np.random.randn(N)
y += yerr * np.random.randn(N)


def lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr):
    m, b, lnf = theta
    model = m * x + b
    inv_sigma2 = 1.0/(yerr**2 + model**2*np.exp(2*lnf))
    return -0.5*(np.sum((y-model)**2*inv_sigma2 - np.log(inv_sigma2)))
def lnprior(theta):
    m, b, lnf = theta
    if -5.0 < m < 0.5 and 0.0 < b < 10.0 and -10.0 < lnf < 1.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf
def lnprob(theta, x, y, yerr):
    lp = lnprior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr)

import scipy.optimize as op
nll = lambda *args: -lnlike(*args)
result = op.minimize(nll, [m_true, b_true, np.log(f_true)], args=(x, y, yerr))
m_ml, b_ml, lnf_ml = result["x"]
init = [0.5, m_ml, b_ml, lnf_ml]

ntemps = 10
nwalkers = 100
ndim = 3
from multiprocessing import Pool
pos = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(ntemps, nwalkers, ndim))
for i in range(ntemps):
    #initialize parameters near scipy optima
    pos[i:,] = np.array([result["x"] + 1e-4*np.random.randn(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)])
pool = Pool(processes=4)
sampler=PTSampler(ntemps,nwalkers, ndim, lnlike, lnprior, loglargs=(x, y, yerr), pool=pool)# args=(x, y, yerr))
#burn-in 
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 1000)
sampler.reset()
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 10000, thin=10)
samples = sampler.chain.reshape((-1, ndim))
print('Number of posterior samples is {}'.format(samples.shape[0]))
#print best fit value together with errors
print(map(lambda v: (v[1], v[2]-v[1], v[1]-v[0]),
                             zip(*np.percentile(samples, [16, 50, 84],
                                                axis=0))))

import corner
fig = corner.corner(samples, labels=["$m$", "$b$", "$\ln\,f$"],
                      truths=[m_true, b_true, np.log(f_true)])
fig.savefig("triangle.png")
```

The only problem when running this code is I get optimal parameters value which are way off the true values. And increasing the number of walkers or samples is not helping in any sense. Can anyone please advice why `tempered-mcmc` is not working here?

**Update:**

I found out a useful package called `ptemcee` (https://pypi.org/project/ptemcee/#description), although the documentation of this package is non-existent. It seems that this package might be useful, any help on how to implement the same linear fitting with this package would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be done with `emcee`?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would like to learn how to implement it with `emcee` just because I have been using `emcee` for simple mcmc fittings.

Comment: What is `f_true`?

Comment: This is a linear model " where the quoted uncertainties are underestimated by a constant fractional amount." It is an exact duplicate of the example presented in the website of `emcee`.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some lines

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from emcee import PTSampler
import corner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as op

t1 = time.time()

np.random.seed(6) # To reproduce results
# Choose the "true" parameters.
m_true = -0.9594
b_true = 4.294
f_true = 0.534

# Generate some synthetic data from the model.
N = 50
x = np.sort(10 * np.random.rand(N))
yerr = 0.1 + 0.5 * np.random.rand(N)
y_1 = m_true * x + b_true
y = np.abs(f_true * y_1) * np.random.randn(N) + y_1
y += yerr * np.random.randn(N)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')


# With emcee

def lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr):
    m, b, lnf = theta
    model = m * x + b
    inv_sigma2 = 1.0/(yerr**2 + model**2*np.exp(2*lnf))
    return -0.5*(np.sum((y-model)**2*inv_sigma2 - np.log(inv_sigma2)))
def lnprior(theta):
    m, b, lnf = theta
    if -5.0 < m < 0.5 and 0.0 < b < 10.0 and -10.0 < lnf < 1.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf
def lnprob(theta, x, y, yerr):
    lp = lnprior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + lnlike(theta, x, y, yerr)


nll = lambda *args: -lnlike(*args)
result = op.minimize(nll, [m_true, b_true, np.log(f_true)], args=(x, y, yerr))
m_ml, b_ml, lnf_ml = result["x"]

init = [0.5, m_ml, b_ml, lnf_ml]

ntemps = 10
nwalkers = 100
ndim = 3

pos = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(ntemps, nwalkers, ndim))
for i in range(ntemps):
    pos[i:, :] = np.array([result["x"] + 1e-4*np.random.randn(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)])

sampler = PTSampler(ntemps, nwalkers, ndim, lnlike, lnprior, loglargs=(x, y, yerr), threads=4) # args=(x, y, yerr))

#burn-in 
print(pos.shape)
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 100)
sampler.reset()
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 5000, thin=10)
samples = sampler.chain.reshape((-1, ndim))

print('Number of posterior samples is {}'.format(samples.shape[0]))

#print best fit value together with errors

p1, p2, p3 = map(lambda v: (v[1], v[2]-v[1], v[1]-v[0]),
                             zip(*np.percentile(samples, [16, 50, 84],
                                                axis=0)))

print(p1, '\n', p2, '\n', p3)

fig = corner.corner(samples, labels=["$m$", "$b$", "$\ln\,f$"],
                      truths=[m_true, b_true, np.log(f_true)])

t2 = time.time()

print('It took {:.3f} s'.format(t2 - t1))

plt.show()
```

The figure I get with `corner` is:

[image]

The important line is

```py
sampler = PTSampler(ntemps, nwalkers, ndim, lnlike, lnprior, loglargs=(x, y, yerr), threads=4)
```

I have used `threads=4` instead of `Pool`.

Look closely at this line `print(p1, '\n', p2, '\n', p3)`, it prints the values of `m_true`, `b_true` and `f_true` you get:

```py
(-1.277782877669762, 0.5745273177144817, 2.0813620981463297) 
(4.800481378230051, 3.1747356851201163, 2.245189235990341) 
(-0.9391847529845194, 1.1196053087321716, 3.6017609114364273)
```

For `f`, you need `np.exp(-0.93918)`, which is `0.3909`, which is close to `0.534`. The values you get are close (`-1.277` compared to `-0.9594` and `4.8` compared to `4.294`), although the errors are not bad (except for `f`). I mean, are you expecting to get the exact numbers? With this method, in my computer, it takes 111 s to complete, is that normal?

Let's try something different. Let's be clear: the problem is not easy when `f_true` is added. I will use `pymc3` (you don't need to know how to use `pymc3`, I want to check the results found by `emcee`).

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import corner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm

t1 = time.time()

np.random.seed(6)
# Choose the "true" parameters.
m_true = -0.9594
b_true = 4.294
f_true = 0.534

# Generate some synthetic data from the model.
N = 50
x = np.sort(10 * np.random.rand(N))
yerr = 0.1 + 0.5 * np.random.rand(N)
y_1 = m_true * x + b_true
y = np.abs(f_true * y_1) * np.random.randn(N) + y_1
y += yerr * np.random.randn(N)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')


with pm.Model() as model: # model specifications in PyMC3 are wrapped in a with-statement
    # Define priors
    f = pm.HalfCauchy('f', beta=5)
    m = pm.Normal('m', 0, sd=20)
    b = pm.Normal('b', 0, sd=20)

    mu2 = b + m * x
    sigma2 = yerr**2 + f**2 * (y_1)**2

    post = pm.Normal('y', mu=mu2, sd=pm.math.sqrt(sigma2), observed=y)

with model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=2000)

print(pm.summary(trace))
pm.traceplot(trace)

all_values = np.stack([trace.get_values('b'), trace.get_values('m'), trace.get_values('f')], axis=1)

fig2 = corner.corner(all_values, labels=["$b$", "$m$", "$f$"],
                      truths=[b_true, m_true, f_true])

t2 = time.time()

print('It took {:.3f} s'.format(t2 - t1))

plt.show()
```

The summary is

```
       mean        sd  mc_error   hpd_2.5  hpd_97.5        n_eff      Rhat
m -0.995545  0.067818  0.001174 -1.123187 -0.857653  2685.610018  1.000121
b  4.398158  0.332526  0.005585  3.767336  5.057909  2746.736563  1.000201
f  0.425442  0.063884  0.000904  0.311037  0.554446  4195.591204  1.000309
```

The important part is the column `mean`, you see that the values found by `pymc3` are close to the true values. The columns `hpd_2.5` and `hpd_97.5` are the errors for `f`, `b` and `m`. And it took 14 s.

The figure I get with `corner` is

[image]

You will say that the results of `emcee` are not quite good, but if you really want more accuracy, you have to modify this function:

```py
def lnprior(theta):
    m, b, lnf = theta
    if -5.0 < m < 0.5 and 0.0 < b < 10.0 and -10.0 < lnf < 1.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf
```

The famous [prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability). In this case, it is flat, and since there are a lot of priors...

Comment: This does not address my concern though. The best fit results are way off from the true values, and the error bars are way too large.